# Supposedly valid regular expression doesn't return any data in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following code:

```
<?php
$stock = $_GET[s]; //returns stock ticker symbol eg GOOG or YHOO
$first = $stock[0];

$url = "http://biz.yahoo.com/research/earncal/".$first."/".$stock.".html";
$data = file_get_contents($url);

$r_header = '/Prev. Week(.+?)Next Week/';
$r_date = '/\<b\>(.+?)\<\/b\>/';

preg_match($r_header,$data,$header);
preg_match($r_date, $header[1], $date);

echo $date[1];
?>
```

I've checked the regular expressions [here](http://www.quanetic.com/regex.php) and they appear to be valid.  If I check just $url or $data they come out correctly and if I print $data and check the source the code that I'm looking for to use in the regex is in there.  If you're interested in checking anything, an example of a proper URL would be http://biz.yahoo.com/research/earncal/g/goog.html

I've tried everything I could think of, including both var_dump($header) and var_dump($date), both of which return empty arrays.

I have been able to create other regular expressions that works.  For instance, the following correctly returns "Earnings":

```
$r_header = '/Company (.+?) Calendar/';
preg_match($r_header,$data,$header);
echo $header[1];
```

I am going nuts trying to figure out why this isn't working.  Any help would be awesome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that the HTML has newlines in it, which you need to incorporate with the s regex modifier, as below

```
<?php
$stock = "goog";//$_GET[s]; //returns stock ticker symbol eg GOOG or YHOO
$first = $stock[0];

$url = "http://biz.yahoo.com/research/earncal/".$first."/".$stock.".html";
$data = file_get_contents($url);

$r_header = '/Prev. Week(.+?)Next Week/s';
$r_date = '/\<b\>(.+?)\<\/b\>/s';


preg_match($r_header,$data,$header);
preg_match($r_date, $header[1], $date);

var_dump($header);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your regex doesn't allow for the line breaks in the HTML  Try:

```
$r_header = '/Prev\. Week((?s:.*))Next Week/';
```

The `s` tells it to match the newline characters in the `.` (match any).

Answer (score 2):

1. Dot does not match newlines by default. Use `/your-regex/s`
2. `$r_header` should probably be `/Prev\. Week(.+?)Next Week/s`
3. FYI: You don't need to escape `<` and `>` in a regex.

Answer (score 2):

You want to add the `s (PCRE_DOTALL)` modifier. By default `.` doesn't match newline, and I see the page has them between the two parts you look for.

**Side note:** although they don't hurt (except readability), you don't need a backslash before `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you're applying the values to the regex as if it's plain text. However, it's HTML. For example, your regex should be modified to parse:

`<a href="...">Prev. Week</a> ...`

Not to parse regular plain text like: "Prev. Week ...."